# Why doesn't GLUT window respond to redisplay requests?

Tags: python, glut, python-multithreading, pyopengl

I have a program that performs most of its work without a display/UI, but then briefly needs to display some content in a low-latency way.  I'm using GLUT via PyOpenGL to display a window in a separate thread, which I then populate with content from the main thread when necessary.  The problem I'm having is that the GLUT window seems to only recognize that a Redisplay request has been issued when the mouse cursor moves across the window.  This seems very weird, and obviously I want the GLUT window to update as soon as it's able, not wait indefinitely for the mouse cursor to move.

I suspect this may be a platform-specific issue.  I've confirmed the behavior is reproducible on Ubuntu 16.04.2 and 14.04.5.

The full code to reproduce is below (requires PyOpenGL).  The desired behavior for this code is for the GLUT window to display black, then automatically switch to red a second later, then green then blue then exit, all without any mouse movement after the script is started.  Instead, the GLUT window will display black at program start and it will stay black indefinitely until the mouse cursor is moved across the window (and then red until the mouse is moved again, etc).  It doesn't matter if the cursor is inside or outside the window -- it must be moved, or else the onDisplay handler will not fire.

How can I make the program below run to completion regardless of what the mouse is doing?

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
import sys
import threading
import time

hWin = None
displayevent = threading.Event()
bgcolor = (0,0,0,1)

def onDisplay():
    print("  [onDisplay] Started")
    glClearColor(*bgcolor)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glutSwapBuffers()
    print("  [onDisplay] Finished")
    displayevent.set()
    print("  [onDisplay] Exiting")

def runGl():
    global hWin

    glutInit(sys.argv)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB)
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)
    hWin = glutCreateWindow("GLWindow")

    glutDisplayFunc(onDisplay)

    print("[runGl] Entering main GLUT loop")
    glutMainLoop()
    print("[runGl] Exited main GLUT loop")


glThread = threading.Thread(target=runGl)
print("[main] Showing GLUT window")
glThread.start()
print("[main] Waiting for GLUT window to initialize")
time.sleep(1)
print("[main] GLUT window initialization (assumed) complete")

colors = [(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)]

for i in range(len(colors)):
    print("[main] --- Iteration %d ---" % i)
    print("[main] Waiting...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("[main] Trigging display update")
    bgcolor = colors[i]
    displayevent.clear()
    glutPostRedisplay()
    print("[main] Waiting for redraw to complete")
    displayevent.wait()
    print("[main] Redraw is complete")

print("[main] Closing window")
glutDestroyWindow(hWin)
print("[main] All done.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `glutPostRedisplay()` from the same thread that GLUT was initialized on.

> How can I call `glutPostRedisplay` on the thread that is fully occupied by `glutMainLoop`

Think about it the other way around. Use the event to tell your main loop that something changed.

```
def display():
    glClearColor(*bgcolor)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glutSwapBuffers()

def idle():
    if displayevent.is_set():
        glutPostRedisplay()
```

*Using `glutIdleFunc(idle)`.*

This way your main loop is continuesly running and checking if `displayevent` is set. Then in your loop instead of `displayevent.wait()` you call `displayevent.set()`.

You could of course have an additional event which you set after calling `glutSwapBuffers()`. Then you could wait on that event.

This is similarly how you would do asynchronized loading. You have a secondary thread load and process the image data. Then when it's done you flag it as such and the main / rendering thread calls `glTexImage2D()`.

Comment: Hmm, that seems reasonable in general, except how can I do that when that thread is irrevocably trapped in the glutMainLoop?  (There isn't even a way to instruct GLUT to exit glutMainLoop)

Comment: Yes there is `glutLeaveMainLoop()`. However it would be easier to know your more specific end goal.

Comment: Ah, perhaps this highlights the same issue -- glutLeaveMainLoop doesn't work from another thread either.  So back to my original comment on this answer: how can I call glutPostRedisplay on the thread that is fully occupied by glutMainLoop?  My end goal is to do CPU work on one thread and periodically display results from that work in a GLUT window (or really, any OpenGL window).  The concrete goal of this code is to have it complete without any mouse movement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that doesn't work because the core problem is that onDisplay never gets called unless there is mouse movement, even though glutPostRedisplay is called from a separate thread.  But, you prompted me to read about controlling GLUT from a separate thread and the answer is that glutPostRedisplay can be called from the glutMainLoop thread by hooking glutIdleFunc and then triggering glutPostRedisplay there (in onIdle) based on a cross-thread signal.

Comment: Meant to use `glutIdleFunc()` as well. I subsequently changed the answer to use it. But yes that is how you would do it.